# Java ME Connector.open() is returning null

Tags: sockets, intellij-idea, java-me, serversocket

I'm currently developing a project for school using Java ME and Intellij. I need to create both a client and server using the javax.microedition.io library. However, I tried running some sample code for creating both a server and a client and I get a return value of null for both of these lines:

1. ServerSocketConnection server = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://:" + port);
2. SocketConnection client = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://" + hostname + ":" + port);

Is there something I'm missing? Intellij has networking permissions and I'm simply trying to test this on my local host. I haven't been able to find any documentation to indicate why these functions would return null. I've tried other protocols as well (including bogus ones) and no exceptions are being thrown at all.

**EDIT**
Turns out all the classes I have found under javax.microedition.io are unimplmented (i.e. simply return null or similar values such as 0) I will make a new post regarding this problem.

Comment: Have you set proper API Permissions?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure, do you mean setting permissions through Intellij or by some other means?

Comment: I don't know Intellij. I use NetBeans. I go to Project Properties, select "Application Descriptor" and add my API Permissions in there. If I don't add the relevant permissions there, the MIDlet won't have them.

Comment: I will try running my project in NetBeans and follow your directions. However, I had trouble in the past getting Java ME working in that IDE. I will let you know my results, thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need to use NetBeans. Although I don't know Intellij I'm sure it has the same options somewhere. Look for "API Permissions" somewhere in the project properties.

Comment: I've realized that my issue wasn't to do with permissions but the Java ME library files themselves. When I looked at the implementation of the Connector class (as well as other classes from javax.microedition.io), all the functions simply returned null and had no substance. I created a new post for this issue. Thank you for your help!